# Sequence of convex non increasing sets convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

I have a question for you. I was wondering whether a non increasing  sequence of convex set converges to a convex set. Here my question made more precise:

Let $\{S_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of convex sets such that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $S_{k+1}\subset S_k$. Say
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} S_k=S.$$

Is $S$ convex?

It sounds right to me, but it would like to have some precise references.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take care that the intersection of nested convex subspaces of a Banach space might be empty. Example [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/an-empty-intersection-of-nested-closed-convex-subspaces-in-a-banach-space/).

Comment: Good point! Thanks! My case concerns to convex sets in the space of $n\times n$ matrices, so it is rather particular. One should first verify that in general the intersection of such a kind of sets is nonempty whenever they are nested.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: are empty sets not convex?

Comment: So finally, is my claim true?

Answer (score 0):

[Convex sets are closed under arbitrary intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Intersections_and_unions), as long as you adopt the "correct" definition where empty sets are trivially convex. Unions of convex sets are frequently not convex, but the union of a sequence of non-decreasing convex sets is convex.

---

In many ways convex sets behave a lot like closed sets of a topological space. For example, the convex hull operator satisfies almost all of the [Kuratowski axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms), except that "preservation of binary union" is replaced by the weaker axiom "preservation of inclusion".